# How to reference an object in many Javascript classes without passing it into every function?

Tags: javascript

In the browser there is not a `gl` object until you make one:

```
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')
```

This means that there it is challenging to reference any of the `gl` properties (like `gl.createBuffer` or `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER`) in something like a `class`.

In C++ these objects are included and therefore accessible without a a particular instance of gl.

How can I create a class which has a member variable whose value is set to some property of a `gl` object?

For instance:

```
class App {
  constructor () {
     this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is not defined here
  }
}
```

I think the most common way is to pass in a `gl` instance into the constructor (i.e.):

```
class App {
  constructor (gl) {
     this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is passed in
  }
}
```

but this seems like it would get annoying if I have to make hundreds of different calls and pass in a `gl` object each time.

Additionally I guess I could define some sort of global `gl` object:
`gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')` and then just assume that there is some global `gl` object everywhere it needs to be accessed, but this seems like a very bad idea.

I would appreciate any ideas on a good, clean design paradigm to get around these issues.

Comment: add that variable to that class `prototype`. Then you can access it like `this.g1`

Comment: But if I have 100 classes, I would have to add it each of those classes too right? Is this better than just passing it to every function?

Comment: What is the problem? The class constructor is only executed when you create an object of that class.... so just make sure you define `gl` before instantiating those class objects.

Comment: @Startec use `extends` keyword otherwise. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is make sure you don't execute any of your class instantiating code before you have assigned a value to `gl`, and then define `gl` in the same context as the classes. For example:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    class App {
        constructor () {
             this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is defined when getting here
        }
    }

    const canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'),
          gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2'),
          app = new App();
    // ... etc
});
```

If your classes are defined outside of a function context and this cannot be changed, then define `gl` on the global object:

```
class App {
    constructor () {
         this.VBO = window.gl.createBuffer() // gl is defined when getting here
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    window.gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    var app = new App();
    // ...etc
});
```

Comment: I like this. I would be concerned about the global variables but I guess I could also wrap it inside an anonymous function

Comment: The first solution uses the event callback as such an *anonymous function*. The second solution should only be used if you cannot move your classes inside such a function for some reason. NB: the `window.` prefix is optional of course, I just added it to clarify that in the second fall-back solution `gl` is global.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the most common way is to pass in a gl instance into the
>   constructor (i.e.):

```
class App {
  constructor (gl) {
     this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is passed in
  }
}
```

> but this seems like it would get annoying if I have to make hundreds of
>   different calls and pass in a gl object each time.

Thats the common way for good reason. Searching the scope-chain until you reach a "gl" object on global scope is much slower, especially if you call it a hundred times in different functions per frame.

It is better to pass the "gl"-object to a class and create an instance-property-reference - so you can access "this.gl" in prototype-Functions, too - without any performance-critical scope-chain-lookups outside the class.

```
class App {
  constructor(gl) { //pass gl
     this.gl = gl; // always create a instance-property for fast access
     this.VBO = this.gl.createBuffer(); // access methods through "this.gl"
     this.foo = new FooGL(gl); // pass "gl" to other classes
  }

  abc() {
     this.gl.doSomeThingABC(); // access methods through "this.gl"
     this.foo.doSomething(); // FooGL has his own "gl" instance-property
                             // to access methods through its own "this.gl"
  }
}
// or
App.prototype.xyz = function()
{
    return this.gl.doSomeThingXYZ(); // access methods through "this.gl"
}

const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
const app = new App(gl);
```

Thats the best method for high performance, even if its more code to write. If you work with WebGL, good performance is the most important to achieve a high framerate.

Of course you can do anything else like extending classes, create singletons or access global properties. But if you want "good, clean [and performant] design", always pass the object-references and create a local property for fast access. Don't save on the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to access that property inside all the instance is to assign that variable to that class's prototype.

Also you can use `extends` keyword to extend the properties from parent class. In the below code `App` and `App2` use the same function `fun2` from Parent protype.

```js
class Parent{
  constructor() {
    this.fun = function(){
     return 'An instance property '
    }
  } 
}

Parent.prototype.fun2 = function(){
  return 'not an instance property'
}

class App extends Parent{
 
  constructor () {
     super();
     this.VBO = App.gl.createBuffer() 
  }
}

App.gl = {
 createBuffer : function(){
   console.log('from App prototype ')
 }
}

var a = new App();
console.log(a.fun())

class App2 extends Parent{

}

var a2 = new App2();
console.log(a2.fun())
console.log(a2.fun2())
```

Comment: `fun` is not a property on the prototype, it **is** an **instance** property because you set it on the current instance which is referenced by `this`. Instance properties !== prototype properties, instance properties **shadow** prototype properties of the same names. Don't believe me?, run this `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Parent.prototype)` you won't see `fun`

Comment: @Dummy how about now?? seting `fun2` in `Parent` prototye.

Comment: You got it. Hope you discover something new. Also, with typescript just create a function inside the class like how define the constructor, that way the function is added on the prototype, instead of doing `MyClass.prototype.function`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton, and every time you import that singleton, it will import the same `gl`.

```
// gl.js    
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

export default gl;

// class1.js
import gl from './gl.js';
class App {
  constructor () {
     this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is not defined here
  }
}

// class2.js
import gl from './gl.js'; // exactly the same gl
class B {
  constructor () {
     this.VBO = gl.createBuffer() // gl is not defined here
  }
}
```

You can read more about singletones in this [book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript).